# How can I list the external libraries accessible from and Oracle DB?

Tags: oracle

When I create a library in oracle using the command;

create library DLL_MyLibrary as 'C:\MyPath\MyLibrary.dll';

it creates a library entry somewhere in the Oracle database. I would like to know how to get a list of the libraries currently in the DB.

Anybody know this? I did about 30 minutes of searching and found nothing.

I am asking because I have created a package and when I call it, it acts as though it is calling a different library.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but for a list of libraries, try:  select * from all_source where type = 'LIBRARY';  For a specific library, try:  select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('LIBRARY', 'SOME_LIB_NAME', 'SOME_SCHEMA') from dual;  The resulting clob should show you the "create library ..." ddl, which you can verify points to the correct ddl

Answer (score 2):

You can search in ALL_LIBRARIES table.

Query:

`select * from ALL_LIBRARIES where upper(LIBRARY_NAME) = 'DLL_MyLibrary';`

Comment: `where upper(LIBRARY_NAME) = 'DLL_MyLibrary';` How is that supposed to return any rows is you are comparing an upper-case string to a mixed-case string?

Answer (score 0):

Tbone got what I needed which was;

select * from all_source where type = 'LIBRARY';

To get what I really needed I just added the user like so;

select * from all_source where type = 'LIBRARY' and owner = 'LIBOWNER';

where 'LIBOWNER' is the actual owner of the library(ies) I was interested in.

This led to an interesting observation. I believe that if you create a library pointing to dll "A" and then build your package/function and reference it. Then you drop the library and recreate it pointing to dll "B", recompile your package. When you reference the function it still points to dll "A". I suspect when I restart the DB, the problem will go away.

Being the curious type, this led me to try the following query;

select type, count(*) from all_source group by type order by type;